# Check size in difficult map

Tags: c++

I have something like

```
map<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int> > >
```

How can I check size of all keys value?

Comment: Please explain what "size of all keys value" means.

Comment: Just try and split the map in parts. And parts of parts. Into something more managable :)

Comment: hm I have 2 key in map, I want to check every vector

Comment: iterate over the values, and sum v.size()

Comment: heh I don't know how :D

Comment: Are you maybe confusion the maps keys with its values? In your case `pair<int,int>` is the keys and `vector<pair<int,int>>` is the values. If you want to know the size of the `pair<int,int>`s you should clarify what you mean with size of that pairs. However I guess you want to know the sizes (possibly accumulated?) of the vectors, right?

Comment: If you don't know how, it's time to get back to the basics of c++ and `std` containers.